# api-error: Please configure a PayPal account with reference transactions in Recurly before accepting PayPal payments

Tags: php, recurly

We use the Recurly.js. Now PayPal payments pro are  available for both Recurly Hosted Payment Pages and Recurly.js.I integrate Paypal as per given docs [Recurly.js](https://docs.recurly.com/js/#paypal) and [Paypal Payment Pro](https://docs.recurly.com/payment-gateways/additional#paypal_payments_pro)

Now facing error  >>>
**api-error: Please configure a PayPal account with reference transactions in Recurly before accepting PayPal payments.**

I integrate paypal payment pro in my recurly account and its status is on (Green Signal).

But running time i am getting these error. 
what should i do ?

Recurly Sample code

```
<script>
      // Configure recurly.js
      recurly.configure({ publicKey: '***************', api: 'https://api.recurly.com/js/v1' });


      // On form submit, we stop submission to go get the token
      $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Reset the errors display
        $('#errors').text('');
        $('input').removeClass('error');

        // Disable the submit button
        $('button').prop('disabled', true);

        var form = this;

        // Now we call recurly.paypal with an object containing a 'description' property. 
        // This will open a new window, beginning the PayPal billing agreement flow. 
        // to tokenize the credit card information, then injects the token into the
        // data-recurly="token" field above
        recurly.paypal({ description: 'test' }, function (err, token) {
          if (err) {
            // Let's handle any errors using the function below
            alert(err);
          } else {
            // set the hidden field above to the token we get back from Recurly
            $('#recurly-token').val(token.id);

            // Now we submit the form!
            form.submit();
          }
        });
      });

      // A simple error handling function to expose errors to the customer
      function error (err) {
        console && console.error(err);
        $('#errors').text('There was a problem intializing the PayPal transaction! Please try again in a few moments.');
        $('button').prop('disabled', false);
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you passed your `recurly.configure` file inside the page you're using `recurly`?

Make sure to call the `recurly.configure` anywhere on your page. An example would be:

```
recurly.configure('sc-ABCDEFGHI123456789');
```

As the document states :

```
not-configured  This error appears when you try to perform an operation without first calling recurly.configure.
```

Source:

https://docs.recurly.com/js/#errors